# AJAX contact form failing to post data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

So I've got this AJAX contact form, the code of which I've used before. I can't work out quite why it isn't working.

```
HTML
<div id="website-contact-form">
<form id="website_contact" name="website_contact">
        <input id="email-address-input" name="website-email" type="text" placeholder="Your email here" class="order-form-input" /><br />
        <textarea name="website-message" placeholder="Please give a brief description of what you have in mind, plus contact details." class="order-form-textarea"></textarea>
        <a href="#" id="submit-website-project" name="submit-website-project" class="send-button"></a>
</form>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit-website-project').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('#email-address-input').val() != ""){

                postForm("ajax/contact-website.php", "website_contact",
                function (data) {

                    if (data == "success") {
                        $('#website-contact-form').
                        html("<br />Thankyou for your enquiry. I'll "+
                             "get in touch shortly.");
                    } else {

                    alert("That didn't work. Try again?");
                    }
                });
        }
    });

}); //END DOCUMENT READY

function postForm(url, form_id, success_func) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("#" + form_id).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            success_func(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

And finally my PHP

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $_POST['email'] = trim(@$_POST['email']);

    $ToEmail = 'barneywimbush:gmail.com';
    $EmailSubject = 'Barneywimbush.com';
    $mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
    $mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
    $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

    $MESSAGE_BODY = "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."";
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["project_description"])."";

    $res = mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader); // or die ("Failure")

    if ($res) {
        echo "success";
    }
    else {
        echo "failed";
    }
}
else {
    echo "failed";
}
```

I'm just getting the alert "That didn't work. Try again?"

Comment: Do you use Google Chrome / Firefox? Check your Network panel to see if the request fires, if so, check the method type, and the request params attempting to be sent.

Comment: It refers to the outer div of the form, sorry I've added that in now. In the net panel, it doesn't appear that any requests are firing. Take a look at it on http://barneywimbush.com/websites and click on order to see it in action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PHP variables for your $_POSTs are incorrect, on checking the Network panel, your form is sending off,

**website-email:** yes@test.com

**website-message:** Test data

Whilst your PHP code is looking $_POST['email'], were it should be $_POST['website-email'];

Change the name attribute of your input elements to change the param name for the request.

Comment: Sorry but it's a bit late, but what do you mean by "Change the name attribute of your input elements to change the param name for the request." ?

Comment: Your input fields,

<input id="email-address-input" name="website-email" type="text" placeholder="Your email here" class="order-form-input" /><br />
        
The name attribute ( name="website-email" ), if you change this to ( name="email" ) in your PHP code, $_POST['email'] will successfully register. Otherwise it would need to be $_POST['website-email']